# How do I recreate a wiped /boot filesystem in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, grub2

I accidentally overwrote the /boot filesystem on a running Ubuntu host where the root fs and swap are LVs, and the kernel, initramfs, etc. are under /boot with grub modules and config under /boot/grub.

How would one go about recreating all the files needed to successfully boot?

```
# mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda1
# mount /dev/sda1 /boot
# apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r` linux-image memtest86+
# mkdir /boot/grub
# grub-install /dev/sda
```

That seems to have recreated most everything, bit is that enough?  I don't want to chance a reboot without some assurance it will complete.

For the paranoid, this may also be a way of creating a backup boot partition on a flash drive if, for example, your boot partition isn't mirrored but root is.

Comment: In either case, I would definitely make sure to have a back up everything else important, especially /home.

Comment: I haven't rebooted yet, but I think I found one more step:  Look up the old UID for /boot in /etc/fstab and set the new fs to it with `tune2fs -U <UUID>` (or print it with `blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sda1` and edit /etc/fstab).  Without that, I suspect it would still boot, but you'd have to mount /boot manually as the UUIDs wouldn't match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a working system, you can just skip part 1 to 5.

1. Boot up a Ubuntu live-cd macthing the version you are using.
2. Mount your normal system partition. X is the drive letter. Y is the partition number:
   `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
3. Only if you have a separate boot partition (where sdYY is the /boot partition designation):
   `sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot`
4. Mount the critical virtual filesystems.
   `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done`
5. Chroot into your normal system device:
   `sudo chroot /mnt`
6. Reinstall GRUB 2 (substitute the correct device with sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number):
   `grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX`
7. Install ubuntu kernel (Internet is required)
   `apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)`
8. Recreate the GRUB 2 menu file (grub.cfg)
   `update-grub`
9. Exit chroot:
   `CTRL-D` on keyboard
   `sudo reboot`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot 
[Reinstall latest linux kernel on Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/202319/reinstall-latest-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-10-04)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I do have a working system, so steps 1-5 weren't necessary.  Step 6 would fail, as linux-generic was still installed.  The link you gave, while useful, described a situation where linux-generic was uninstalled.  Since mine was still installed according to dpkg, but the files were just deleted, I had to give apt-get the --reinstall option for the specific kernels.It looks as if the steps I outlined in my question hit the same points as your answer, except that the grub-install should be before the kernel reinstall (or a separate call to update-grub).

Comment: The `grub-install --recheck` is just to be sur that MBR is in a working condition; I do not think the order matters, it handles only the MBR. `update-grub` is to rebuild grub.cfg with the "new" kernel. But I'm glad to see that you have got it to work. :)

Comment: Yes this is right, I don't why I have just wrote `apt-get install ..`. Sry.

Comment: FWIW, I ran grub-install without the --recheck option, and that seemed to repopulate the /boot/grub directory with all the grub2 modules, images, and lists.  update-grub (called during the kernel reinstall) then added the grub.cfg.  The MBR wasn't touched, so I wasn't worried about that.

Comment: Ooh yes, that's right :) I had forgotten that it is the `grub-install` that makes the /boot/grub - Thanks :)

Comment: I would like to complete Diblo Dk answer; if you have separated /boot partition, you have to change the matching entry in the /etc/fstab before reboot.

Comment: I write this as remainder for my self, that maybe helps others. 
In my virtual machines the /dev/sdYY points to the efi partition, and /boot is just a normal directory. Remember to `sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot/efi` not /mnt/boot

Comment: Additionally to those steps, I had to call update-initramfs manually

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using those fine backups you have made and restore them.

If no backups (bad answer)...your easiest route might be a reinstall.

If you have not destroyed the filesystem metadata, even after a reboot you can go in and use a Linux rescue mode boot to get to the information.  Your process looks ok but I can provide no guarantees, have you compared the contents of your resulting /boot file with another running system?  That might be interesting to be sure you have everything.

Comment: You missed the point entirely.  The goal is to not reinstall.  The system is still up and running.  Sorry if that was not clear to you.

Comment: Apparently not able to reboot....your options are nearly non-existent in fixing a broken running system while it is running.  Thus I provided the reasonable and prudent alternative.  Personally, I'd not trust a system fixed in such a manner for production purposes.

Comment: Why not trust it?  That's one of the greatest strengths of UNIX and UNIX-like systems such as Linux; it's modularity and robustness.  If reinstalling a couple of packages and running a standard update script is enough to restore a specific directory, then I'd say it's proven its production readiness.

Comment: the only remaining question is whether or not the initramfs contains everything the original one did.  I believe all additions are corralled in a specific directory on the root fs so they can be added when update-initramfs is called, and I see in the logs that was called when I reinstalled the kernel.  Ultimately, if it reboots successfully once, I'm guessing there's' no reason to distrust it at all, but I want to have an alternate up and running before I test a reboot.